# visual studio 2005 web page is not displayed after run

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

Page is not shown in  the browser
I am using VS2005. I am working on Web Project. But my problem is whenever I am running my page ..the URL .I am getting is this http: //localhost:23644/UI/LoginUI.aspx
but the page I am getting is "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" For other web application its giving the same browser message ..though the URL is changing to the specific URL.

Can anyone help me in this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Can you please check if the localhost server (IIS) is started? For Visual Studio though,the IDE starts the server by itself, but you can always cross-check if the server is started via services.msc. Check also if the port 23644 is free.